# Accessing the datetime.time (00:00 - 23:59) format in a numeric data type

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a 24-HR averaged data that is indexed according from 00:00 - 23:59, at an interval of 1 minute. This leads to 1440 data points corresponding to each minute. I want to map these timestamps to their numerical indices ranging from 0-1440 (as there 1440 minutes in the entire day).

For example, 00:00 ->0, 00:01->1, 00:02->2 ...23:58->1339, 23:59->1440

> > time = 01:11 dtype:datetime.time
> >     time.func()
> >        71

I tried to search if there is any such functionality in pandas for the datetime.time format. But, I couldn't find any.

If there is no in-built functionality in pandas for this, the other way might be to write a function that maps the specific datetime.time to an index (0-1440) .

Comment: If `00:00` is index `0` then `23:59` must be `1439`. This should do it: `time.hour * 60 + time.minute`

Answer (score 0):

pandas doesn't have a native `time` dtype, but it does have timedelta:

```
In [11]: t = dt.time(10, 15)

In [12]: t.hour * 60 + t.minute  # total minutes (this may suffice!)
Out[12]: 615

In [13]: pd.to_timedelta((t.hour * 60 + t.minute), unit='m')
Out[13]: Timedelta('0 days 10:15:00')
```

Note: You may be able to work from timedelta from the start (either in parsing or by calculation):

```
In [14]: pd.to_timedelta('10:15:00')
Out[14]: Timedelta('0 days 10:15:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look and see if this is what you wanted:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['23:57', '10:39', '4:03'], columns=['Time'])
```

This data frame looks like:

```
    Time
0  23:57
1  10:39
2   4:03
```

Then we can apply this function on our column:

```
df['Time'].apply(lambda x: int(pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M').strftime('%H:%M:00'), unit='m').total_seconds()/60))
```

Of which the output is:

```
0    1437
1     639
2     243
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

Here we use apply to apply the same function to all elements of the column.

1. Convert to datetime format (here I specified the format using '%H:%M' to ensure we were explicitly converting the time to hours and minutes.
2. Format the time with the additional seconds element by adding ':00' using strftime, this is because pd.to_timedelta will want the time in 'hh:mm:ss' format
3. Then we get the total_seconds() of the timedelta and divide by 60 to get minutes
4. Convert to an integer to get your final format.